# top 30 distinct records order by latest LastModifiedDatetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I executed the following query, containing columns SearchText, SearchURL, LastModifiedDateTime, Country

```
 select Top 30 * from SearchHistory  order by LastModifiedDateTime desc
```

There are a lot of duplicate records in this. I need distinct(SearchURL) records order by latest  LastModifiedDatetime.

I tried this query:

```
 SELECT Top 30 *  FROM   (SELECT *,  Row_number()
                                             OVER(
                                             PARTITION BY SearchURL
                                             ORDER BY LastModifieddateTime desc) AS RN
                                             FROM   SearchHistory where searchtext is not null )A
                                        WHERE  RN = 1
```

but I get different set of results altogether (very old records are  at top).

I need the **top 30 distinct(searchurl) records order by LastModifiedDatetime desc**

Comment: Then use `ORDER BY LastModifieddateTime DESC` instead

Comment: Your query seems fine as it is, don't know what are you expecting

Comment: I expect the top 30 distinct(searchurl) records order by LastModifiedDatetime desc but my query returns some old records at top,

Comment: Well, I assumed that you are also using `order by LastModifiedDatetime desc` after the `WHERE RN = 1`

Comment: No I didnot. I will try that one.

Comment: well that works. Thanks Lamak. But i did the same thing after Order by clause. isn't?

Comment: You are confusing the `ORDER BY` inside the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()`, which only says how you order the row number, with the `ORDER BY` at the end of the query, that orders your whole `SELECT` after the filter has been done

Comment: If you solved your issue you should post your solution as an answer for future readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler alternative using grouping:

```
SELECT TOP 30 SearchURL, MAX(LastModifiedDateTime) AS LastModifiedDateTime
FROM SearchHistory
GROUP BY SearchURL
ORDER BY LastModifiedDateTime DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
The only thing I missed is to add the order by clause after RN. I was under an impression that ORDER BY LastModifieddateTime desc after searchURL will take care it.

```
 SELECT Top 30 *  FROM   (SELECT *,  Row_number()
                                         OVER(
                                         PARTITION BY SearchURL
                                         ORDER BY LastModifieddateTime desc) AS RN
                                         FROM   SearchHistory where searchtext is not null )A
                                    WHERE  RN = 1 ORDER BY LastModifieddateTime desc
```